# Trigger script editor when specific cell is changed (Google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a data snapshot on google sheets that will automatically run when a specific cell is edited. How should I do that? I'm not from coding background but so far I've found 2 sources and tried to combine them but when I tested it out, it's giving me error. I want to copy values from A2 to E2 of Snapshot sheet and append row every time B2 is changed. Please advise.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Snapshot");
 var source = sheet.getRange("A2:E2");
 var values = source.getValues();
   if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B2'){
     sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
    }}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the following: what you spreadsheet looks like, what cell needs to trigger the change, what your result should look like. Please be very specific.

Comment: Row 2 in Snapshot sheet is a constantly changing row. What I'm hoping to achieve is if the 'Name' is changed (i.e. cell B2 of Snapshot) then the whole row A2: E2 will be first recorded as a snapshot on row 3, and if B2 changes again, it'll be recorded on row 4, then row 5 and so on. My first tab 'Receipt' would be like a front-end sheet, and then 'Snapshot' from row 3 onwards is to record down history of the receipt. This is the spreadsheet I've created: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XwVAF6DqIaREA9Cvxz2IvsON5vFJc0gJjHHPR9ZKH4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The B2 in Snapshot is a formula which displays the value of F1 in Receipt sheet. So, the onEdit is not triggered on change of name.

The name changes in F1
I tried the below code and it is working

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rsht=ss.getSheetByName("Receipt");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Snapshot");
  var source = sheet.getRange("A2:E2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'F1'){
     sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
  }}
```